# Reliable alert dialogs from the shell

Tags: xorg, notification, workspaces, zenity, guake

I'd like to have a message pop up in response to various system events, mostly in order to be able to set reminders for myself from a shell session.  There are a few ways to do this; `zenity` seems to be the most polished.  However, I've found at least two problems with zenity:

1. Messages do not appear on all workspaces.  I tried using the gtk option `--screen` to control this, but they just appear on the current workspace regardless.  So if I am switching workspaces as the message comes up, I will not see it.
2. Messages do not appear above all other windows.  Specifically, if I am using `guake`, a new `zenity` message will appear below the `guake` window and I won't be able to see it.

I tried a few other apps a while back.  Both `gmessage` and `xmessage` exhibited problem **1**; `gmessage` also exhibited problem **2**.  I did find that `kalarm`, which can be scripted from the command line, worked acceptably, but I'm trying to avoid running the KDE stack if possible, and would prefer something lightweight with `zenity`'s versatility.

It seems that it might be possible to arrange for these problems to be resolved by setting the WM_CLASS, but I'm in a bit over my head there.  It might also be possible to make modifications to the window after it launches with a script, but again I'm not sure where to look for resources on that.

#### update

As suggested by @geirha, I've looked into using `notify-send` (via the package [libnotify-bin](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libnotify), which appears to be a client to [notify-osd](https://launchpad.net/notify-osd)).  There are numerous problems with this framework, for which I've filed [a](https://bugs.launchpad.net/notify-osd/+bug/746172) [few](https://bugs.launchpad.net/notify-osd/+bug/746175) [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/notify-osd/+bug/746177) [reports](https://bugs.launchpad.net/notify-osd/+bug/694224).  I'm hoping that devilspie can provide workarounds for some or all of these issues, or that there is another notification system which works more reliably.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you want `notify-send`?

Otherwise, there's [devilspie](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Devilspie), which allows you to say things like "all windows with this name (or of this class or with this role), shall be visible on all workspaces".

Comment: Is there a way to get notifications sent by `notify-send` to be displayed until acknowledged?  According to [the spec](http://www.galago-project.org/specs/notification/0.9/x320.html), setting the urgency to critical should do this, but notify-osd doesn't seem to respect these rules.  When I send `notify-send -u critical Testing "This is a test of the emergency broadcast system"`, it is displayed for 10 seconds and then disappears.

Comment: Ahh, okay.. it looks like setting the `--expire-time` to zero will do this.  The first time I tried that I thought it was actually displaying for 0 seconds, because I didn't see it.  It was hidden under guake.  Notifications with expiry times are displayed above guake (using a completely different skin).